# Find subtract IPSet

Tags: python, cidr

I would like to be able to get an ip filter using netaddr in python but I don't know how to subtract two ips to create on CIDR range.  Instead I am getting two separate ranges.

```
from netaddr import *

allnets = IPSet(['0.0.0.0/0'])
ip = IPSet(['8.8.8.8', '8.8.8.4'])

for ips in ip:
     print allnets - ip
```

I would like to get one IPset object that filters both ips, not two sets of ranges that filter each ip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression you are searching for is `allnets - ip`. That produces "one IPset object that filters both ips".

Consider this program:

```
from netaddr import *

allnets = IPSet(['0.0.0.0/0'])
ip = IPSet(['8.8.8.8', '8.8.8.4'])
filtered = allnets - ip

assert '8.8.8.8' not in filtered
assert '8.8.8.4' not in filtered
assert '8.8.8.7' in filtered
assert '192.0.2.17' in filtered
assert '203.0.113.1' in filtered
```

Comment: Thanks!  Very helpful.